# How to use string find_first_of buffer form (size_t n parameter)

Tags: c++, string

I understand the usage of the other forms of find_first_of, but for the life of me can not figure out (or find an answer to) how to use the third (buffer?) form of this function. What does the "size_t n" parameter do? The documentation states that it is the number of character values to search for, but what does that mean? Number of occurrences in the string, number of different characters to search for? Position to start in original string or string being searched?

Comment: Hi @Tristan, please provide the function prototype for `find_first_of` as well as links, or snippets, of whatever documentation you've previously researched. This will help for us to narrow down what exactly you're looking at

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll be more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [`std::string::find_first_of()` of cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/), since that declaration seems like the one you are searching for... but believe me, don't take up documentation from there... use some other reliable site like [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com) that clearly defines what each function and argument does...

---

**The *third* declaration of the member function from the site is the 
 second declaration from [cppreference's `std::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), the declaration of the function from cppreference is the following:**

```
size_type find_first_of( const CharT* s, size_type pos, size_type count ) const;
```

> **Note:**
>
> Before even going as far to know *how* find_first_of is declared, we must know *how* it works...
>
> > <sub>Taken for en.cppreference.com definition of the find_first_of function:</sub>
> >
> > "Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in the given character sequence. The search considers only the interval [pos, size()). If the character is not present in the interval, npos will be returned."
>
> *Which can be interpreted as the following:*
>
> *1)* Think of the buffer here like an array of characters and what this function does is checks for all characters individually inside the string...
>
> *2)* In other words, it iterates over the buffer with all characters of the string individually...
>
> *3)* The third argument, simply an argument that takes the length which needs to be found... main cases would be when you are lazy enough to do a `std::string::substr()`...
>
> ---
>
> **For example:** `some_str.find_first_of("this_will_be_found", 10, 5)`...
>
> *This line will check for all individual characters till 5 characters only, since count is **5** (`'t'`, `'h'`, `'i'`, `'s'`, `'_'`**... there,... 5 of them!**) inside the buffer `some_str` **from the index 10**... (Note that indices start from 0, not 1...)*

Now, in order to not get you bored, here is the explanation of the declaration (*Finally!*):

Here, the *find_first_of* is an overloading function whose one of given declarations is such as given above...

*1)* `size_type` is nothing more than an unsigned integer, which is commonly used as a *type for sizes* since an unsigned integer cannot have a negative value, *except zero (0), being a plus-minus number which is still allowed...*

*2)* `const CharT* s` is obviously `const char* s` since the string is a `std::string` (a string buffer of characters, *alternatively `wchar_t` or `unsigned short` instead of `char` for wide string*, `std::wstring`)...

*3)* `pos`, like you might have already guessed, is the starting point from where the function should start its finding...

*4)* `count` is also an unsigned int (one that does not allow values less than zero, that is negative numericals...), which is just an argument that defines how many characters inside the buffer to find... since find_first_of searches for all characters individually, not one buffer at once...

*5)* Lastly, this function is a *constant function*, that is it has a `const` specifier, and will not take part in modifying any kind of variables... expect [`mutable`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-mutable-keyword/)s...

Comment: Ah thank you! Very thorough explanation, I understand. And apologies for not being more clear, I was sort of under the impression that cplusplus.com was something of the "official" documentation page for c++ standard library. I'll make sure to post snippets next time (and use cppreference instead!).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the overload

```
size_type find_first_of(const CharT* s, size_type pos, size_type count)
```

---

> What does the "size_t n" parameter do?

The third argument is simply the length of the buffer pointed by the first argument. The buffer must be at least as long as `n`. It can be longer, but the characters after the first `n` will not be searched for.

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration have a semi-colon?